# Headless Chrome REPL not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

When I try to run:

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --repl http://google.com
```

getting infinite:

```
[0829/155519.758686:INFO:headless_shell.cc(303)] Type a Javascript expression to evaluate or "quit" to exit.
>>> {"result":{"type":"undefined"}}
>>> {"result":{"type":"undefined"}}
>>> {"result":{"type":"undefined"}}
>>> {"result":{"type":"undefined"}}
...
```

Google Chrome 60.0.3112.113 on Ubuntu 16.04

Is it a bug in Chrome?

Comment: Same issue.  I'm surprised it seems like no one else on the internet has this problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the binary  /opt/google/chrome/chrome  directly not google-chrome which points to bash script /usr/bin/google-chrome.

Taken from comments in

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#screenshots

Comment: did not work for me :( 
```/opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --disable-gpu --repl http://google.com
[0315/143607.580608:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0315/143607.607225:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Answer (score 4):

type this

```
 alias chrome=/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

then use chrome

```
 chrome --headless --disable-gpu --repl http://google.com
```