# Headless Chrome in REPL mode doesn't work - spams console with an error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

When I try to run Chrome in Headless, REPL mode with:

> chrome --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --repl

I'm getting an endless spam of

> {"result":{"type":"undefined"}}

It's pretty much the same problem as described here:
[Headless Chrome REPL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939872/headless-chrome-repl-not-working)

But since I'm trying to run it on Windows 7, I'm not sure if that solution applies to me

Edit:
I forgot to add, I'm using a 62.0.3202.94 Chrome version