# Keep Chrome running in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I want to use Chrome browser in headless mode to produce images (PNG, JPEG) out of SVG graphic. Code works in normal interactive mode, but I have problems to use it in headless mode.

My main problem is that headless Chrome exits before drawing of HTML page is completed. As I understand, if I start Chrome with following arguments:

`chromium --headless http://myserver.org`

It exits together with `document.onload` event. But at this moment not all data fetched from the server (I using XMLHttpRequest) and therefore drawing is not complete.

I found workaround if I start chrome with debugging port enabled like:

`chromium --headless --remote-debugging-port=7777 http://myserver.org`

But this is not that I want, especially when I do not have privileges to open http ports on the node. Is there possibility to let Chrome running longer with other flags? I check a [lot of them](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but did not found appropriate one. Or is there any other methods to postpone exit of the headless Chrome?

Comment: I found slightly better workaround with `--remote-debugging-socket-fd=0`, but it does not work on Windows. And still it is not a solution for the problem.

Comment: Another solution which I also found - add <script> tag to the html page, which is not returned immediately by `myserver.org`. In that case chrome waits forever - or at least long enough that my drawing is completed.

Comment: i ended up using `--remote-debugging-port=0` which assigns a random free port by the OS (works on Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424041/4830701

Copy pasted here for reference

> Use the binary /opt/google/chrome/chrome directly not google-chrome which points to bash script /usr/bin/google-chrome.
>
> Taken from comments in
>
> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#screenshots

Comment: Yes, seems to be `--repl` flag is possible way to keep headless chrome running after all scripts are loaded. Thanks for good tip!